# Display X applications on an Android system

Tags: debian, x11, chroot, android

Host system: Android 3.2.1 Honeycomb
Chroot system: Debian Testing lxde
Hardware: Asus eee pad transformer tablet nvidia arm architecture

Note 1: The Debian system boots on this hardware, thus it has adequate graphical drivers.

Note 2: I am looking for a way to do this without VNC.

1) What do I need to install on the host system to run the chroot system's Midori browser so that it is displayed on the host Android GUI?

I want to do it like this:

```
root-chroot@localhost$: export DISPLAY=:0.0  
root-chroot@localhost$: midori
```

Comment: I had trouble understanding your, I edited it from what I gathered based on your reply to Renan, please clarify if my edit wasn't what you meant.

Comment: Do you want to be able to run Android applications in the background while you have X applications displayed? Do you want the X applications in an Android frame with the top bar, full screen, or indifferent?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a new X server that has been written in java:

http://my20percent.wordpress.com/2012/02/27/android-x-server/

It is open source:

http://code.google.com/p/android-xserver/

It has been forked and reworked:
https://github.com/nwrkbiz/android-xserver

And available on F-Droid (search for 'x server').

This is currently optimised in terms of keymappings for a phone so will need a bit of customisation if you want to use it on a tablet... Also a lot of programs seem to complain about a lack of features.

I think this is exactly what you are looking for!

Answer (score 1):

I never used Android, but I think that if you have a X server, like [this](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.theqvd.android.x&hl=pt_BR), running in the Android side, it should be enough.

Do note that it does not "run" your application inside Android; your application runs in the chroot and only its display is forwarded to the X server.

Comment: right. Yes, if I could run an X server on the host side that would be great but this AndroiX does not seem downloadable or even a real project.

Comment: And indeed, that project seems to be dead, sorry. The closest I can find in the Android Market is https://market.android.com/details?id=com.theqvd.android.x&hl=pt_BR.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using the X protocol (and an X server on Android), one can use VNC. I've read that VNC has been a more popular solution in this case.

You can look for VNC solutions at http://android.stackexchange.com.